# Specifying API version in Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to move to Facebook's newer API versions (v2 and above). I'm still not sure if I'm going to also update to the newest SDK (v4.4) or keep my old (v2). But I don't see any way to specify the API version in any of them. All I see in the docs are how to do that in manual calls (`/v2.0/me`) or in different SDKs. This is the API docs I found about versioning calls: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions

How do I specify the API versioning through the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the following example from the [PHP SDK v4 README](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4#usage):

```
$me = (new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me'
))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

echo $me->getName();
```

We can make the same request with an explicit version (e.g. `v2.3`):

```
$me = (new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me',
  null,
  'v2.3'
))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

echo $me->getName();
```

The 3.x SDK doesn't have the concept of versioning so you'd need to add `v2.x` to the front of your request paths yourself.

Comment: Can you help me understand what's the null for?

Comment: Sure, you can see here that the fourth argument is `$parameters` but we're not passing in any query parameters so we can it to `null`: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php#L187